# Action Attributes not showing on jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea, struts2

So I'm following some basic tutorials where I try to show an attribute from an Action-Class through the property-tag. Unfortunately this results in showing nothing at all. But I can call actions via the action-tag.

Here my files

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Struts Blank</display-name>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">

            <action name="somebasic" class="Basic">
                    <result>/pages/Login.jsp</result>
            </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"  %>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
This is a test page...

<p>
  should show firstname and lastname:
  <s:property value="firstname"/>
  <s:property value="lastname"/>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**basic.java**

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class Basic extends ActionSupport{
    private String firstname = "me";
    private String lastname = "I";

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

As already mentioned, if I put an action-tag in the .jsp file, the called action would be triggered (when setting breakpoint). So probably I'm missing some configuration-thing or something. Does somebdoy had this issue too?

I' running my webapp on a Tomcat server and I'm using Intellij 14 as IDE.

Edit: Thanks to Aleksandr M for the eureka moment. I totally misunderstood the action concept. My assumption was that action attributes were already initialised when wanting to access them. But they must be executed before using them (via URL or action-tag).

Comment: You need to call an action that will take you to some jsp. Pages shouldn't be accessed directly.

Comment: but that doesn't have to do with my problem, right? The property-tag should be able to show attributes even on the index site without any action

Comment: What should it show if action isn't being executed?

Comment: It should at least show the predefined attributes `firstname` and `lastname`,or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Predefined values in action which you haven't executed. (Sarcastic quote needed here.)

Comment: ok... So in order to use those values I have to execute the somebasic-action (defined in struts.xml)? Even if I want it to show on the landlingpage?

Comment: You should redirect from the landingpage to some action.

Comment: You should name action class is `BasicAction`, it's Struts's convention.

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 is a MVC framwork where struts mapping takes you to action and based on action results it show the Jsp Page. 
add one action in your Struts action class and it will take you to your jsp page.

eg--

```
public String execute(){
return "success";
}
```

and also mapping in struts.xml will be...

```
<action name="default" method="execute" class="your class name">
        <result name="success" >fully qualified jsp page url</result>
    </action>
```

to learn struts2 properly go to javabrains and start watching tutorials.